# Spring Boot Deployment Strategy

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

Am implementing the swagger 2 using Spring Boot. Using Dependencies-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

It works good. But want to implement swagger in such a way that in production
swagger does not get deployed. Also will it be possible to host the swagger build differently than the application build on different host machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to do this.

1. Maven profile

   By intrudue a maven profile like 'swagger' and add the `springfox-swagger-ui` related depdencenty to this maven profile. As maybe you need to use some swagger annotations in the java code, so it cannot eliminate the `springfox-swagger2` dependency.
2. Spring profile( should be more better than option 1 )

   For a standard spring-boot swagger2 config class, for example you can add the `@Profile("swagger")` annoation to enable the swagger2 integration only when add the `spring.profiles.active=swagger` in app running.

For the different host machines, I has no idea about that, but as my understanding, swagger will select all the spring boot endpoints so suppose you cannot leave them alone. But there is a [library](https://github.com/tokuhirom/springfox-swagger2-actuator) which can provides a way to publish springfox-swagger2 on spring boot actuator. so you can add `management.port=8181` property in `application.properties` to makes spring-boot-actuator run on another TCP port.

Comment: Thank Liping for the reply..But using profiles the class with annotation @EnableSwagger2 still gets loaded and the swagger gets activated by default.

Comment: @Rameez By using spring `@Profile`, if the corresponding profile is not active, the bean will not be processed.